# delete row 2d array based on value second column

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I have a viewScope with an array, for example :

```
viewScope.myTest = [];
viewScope.myTest.push(["row1col1", "row1col2", "row1col3"]);
viewScope.myTest.push(["row2col1", "row2col2", "row2col3"]);
etc ..
```

I would like to make a new viewScope array for example viewScope.mySelection[] with all values of the first viewScope array , except the ones where for example column 2 contains "row1col2".

In ssjs it's not possible to use splice so that's not an option.

I found following OpenNtf snippet , but that doesn't seem to work for my situation :  [remove entry from array](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=remove-an-entry-from-an-array-of-strings)

or is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Server-side JavaScript arrays do support the splice function. The problem in your case is that when setting `viewScope.myTest=[];` the array (com.ibm.jscript.std.ArrayObject) is converted into a vector (**[java.util.Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)**) which does not support the splice function. To circumvent this you can

(A) use the **remove**(n) function to remove the nth element of the vector or

(B) save the 2-dimensional array in a sub-object:

```
viewScope.myTest = { data:[] };
viewScope.myTest.data.push(["row1col1", "row1col2", "row1col3"]);
viewScope.myTest.data.push(["row2col1", "row2col2", "row2col3"]);
```

to prevent the conversion into a vector and be able to use **splice**(n,1) to remove the nth row.